# Time based mobile silenting code not working correctly using services in android

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am making an android app on time based silencing and desilenting the mobile phone.I am using service for this purpose But my time based silenting mobile code is not executing by the service,The service starts and ends correctly as i have written toasts for my confirmation but is not continuously checking the time. kindly help me in this case.
Here is service my code.
    //This is my service class code

```
    package com.example.muhammadirteza.cm;

    import android.app.Service;  

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;


    public class MyService1 extends Service {


        public MyService1() {

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "service added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            super.onCreate();
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


            int l = 0;
            double latitude = 34.1;
            double longitude = 73.1;
            AudioManager audioManager;
            double timezone = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())) / (1000 * 60 * 60);

            prayerTime prayers = new prayerTime();
            prayers.setTimeFormat(prayers.Time12);
            prayers.setCalcMethod(prayers.Karachi);
            prayers.setAsrJuristic(prayers.Hanafi);
            prayers.setAdjustHighLats(prayers.AngleBased);
            int[] offsets = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            prayers.tune(offsets);
            Date now = new Date();


            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.setTime(now);
            ArrayList a = prayers.getPrayerTime(c2, latitude, longitude, timezone);

            Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();

            int x = c3.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int y = c3.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int z = c3.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "hello ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, " maghrib hour  is " + prayers.maghrib_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, " maghrib minutes  is " + prayers.maghrib_minutes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, " z is  " + z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, " y  is " + y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (z == prayers.fajr_hours && y == prayers.fajr_minutes) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Fajr entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in de silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (z == prayers.dhuhr_hours && y == prayers.dhuhr_minutes) {

                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in de silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (z == prayers.asr_hours && y == prayers.asr_minutes) {
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "now in de silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (z == prayers.maghrib_hours && y == prayers.maghrib_minutes) {
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "now in silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    //                                Toast.makeText(this, "now in de silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (z == prayers.isha_hours && y == prayers.isha_minutes) {
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "now in silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "now in de silent mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            //if(l>=0) {


          //  onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            //}
            //l++;


            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        }


    }
    I am calling it in mainactivity through

    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService1.class);
    startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service will be getting killed by android.

If you block any android life-cycle method for more than 10 seconds android will kill the service.

You need to move the code out of `onStartCommand()` into a method and have the code run asynchronously. In your case the `onStartCommand()` probably should only contain `return START_STICKY` to keep the service alive and let it run asynchronous background operations.